# Laravel 4 Routing - Is it possible to name a controller in route group?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im pretty sure this is not possible but I would like to know ifs there is some way
to name a controller in a Route::group();

And then specify the function names in the route::group().

Example:

```
Route::group(['uses'=>'HomeController'], function(){
    Route::get('/', ['function'=>'getIndex']);
    Route::post('/', ['function'=>'postIndex']);
    Route::put('/', ['function'=>'putIndex']);
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've provided all it seems like you want to do is use `Route::controller()`.

```php
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

Then just make sure that you name your methods `getIndex`, `postIndex`, `putIndex`, and so on and so forth.